# Request goes through fine in Chrome, Insomnia, Postman, etc, but not in Node

Tags: node.js, http, https, request, http-status-code-403

I'm having problems with 2 servers, one of them is an akamaized storage server, and the other is an apache server. I can request them in Chrome, Postman, Insomnia, etc, but if I attempt to make a request to them in Node with the `request` library, they both send back a 403. I've completely replicated the request headers from chrome, insomnia, and postman, and nothing changes with any of them.

Any help is appreciated, I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out they're both blocking requests from OVH servers.